# TFS 08 - Can't find AgentService.asmx

Tags: tfs

We have a notification service running on our TFS server which automatically modifies certain work items when they are created so they are assigned to the right people and so on.

Over the weekend a patch was applied to our TFS server and since then the notification service appears to be broken.

When ever it runs we get an error in the Event Viewer which indicates there was a problem accessing `http://<our-tfs>:8080/Build/v2.0/AgentService.asmx`.

I've looked in the folder which IIS maps `Build` to, and it's true, AgentService.asmx does not exist.

Does anyone know where that file may get moved to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the problem was a miss-configured Build Agent (was pointing to the wrong server). Full details can be found on a blog post here: http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/KarlKopp/~3/VFmWhwwGyUk/tfs-the-case-of-the-phantom-build-agent

Answer (score 1):

The AgentService.asmx is the web service hosted by the Visual Studio Team Foundation Build service on a team foundation build agent.  The Build Agent service actually makes this URL available via WCF and so does't show up under IIS.  By default the build agent is configured to run on port 9191 though so that it does not conflict with the default port for Team Foundation Server application tier (8080) if a build agent is also installed on the same machine hosting Team Foundation Server.

Do you want to check that the service "Visual Studio Team Foundation Build" is running?  If there has been an error in communicating with the build agent then you may have re-set the status of the agent to get TFS to talk to it again (by right clicking on the Builds node in Team Explorer and selecting Build Agents...)

However, I'm not sure that this event is your problem.  Do you happen to know which patch was recently applied to your TFS or where the web service is that you get TFS to send an event to?

Good luck,

Martin.

Comment: Our TFS build server is installed on a different machine to the actual TFS instance. Where is the configuration for this URL done so it can be pointed to the correct machine?